# получение определнных данных о пользователе из базы python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

У меня есть база данных. Так же есть переменная, в которую записан `email` пользователя. Такой вопрос:

**Как получать нужную мне информацию(в моем случае это `born_date` и `phone_number`) о конкретном пользователе по его `email`.**

Попробовал так как ниже написал, но не работает. Помогите составить запрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['POST'])
    def login_post():
    data = request.json
    data_list = list(data.values())

    data_list = str(data_list)
    doc_data = data_list.split()[2][:-4]

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number,  FROM users.data WHERE email = 'doc_data'")
    account = cur.fetchall()

    return render_template('profile.html', doc_data=doc_data)
```

`html:`

```
<h2>{{ doc_data }}</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = '%s'" % doc_data.replace("'", "''"))
```

Пояснение:  убрали запятую (ошибка синтаксиса) и вставили переменную, экранировав апострофы (`'`).

Comment: сделал `print(account), в консоли скобки вывел пустые
`

Comment: @abby сделайте `print(doc_data)` и выясните, что и почему неправильно извлекается из запроса пользователя.

Comment: при  `print(doc_data)` он выводт просто мейл. т.е в этом случае все работет

Comment: Уверены? Тут даже лишний пробел может привести к тому, что результат будет пуст.

Comment: да. перепроверил. может то что я хочу получить 2 значения сразу(`born_date` и `phone_number`), а переменная одна? из-за этого может быть?

Comment: @abby, нет, с кодом всё в порядке. Попробуйте выполнить запрос в консоли MySQL вручную.

Comment: попробовал, то что вы написали. ошиюку синтаксиса дает

Comment: Вы скопировали прямо точь-в-точь или сделали верный запрос вида `SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = 'ваш_email'`?

Comment: переписал как вы написали. получил и дату и номер. как бы это перенести в код теперь мне.

Comment: @abby значит, email все-таки не так парсится. Проверьте, есть ли пробелы до или после электронного адреса.

Comment: в общем получилось. Сделал как вы написали, только тут изменил `doc_data.replace("'", ""))`

Comment: у меня только последний вопрос если можно. Как эти 2 переменные получать на `html` странице? Что-то не рендериться у меня..

Comment: @abby что-что???

Comment: ну в `render_template` прописал их, а на странице не отображаются

Comment: @abby вставите в шаблон в нужных местах `{{account.0.0}}` и `{{account.1.1}}`, перед этим передав в `render_template` аргумент `account`.

Comment: сделал так, все равно не получаю `return render_template('profile.html', account_z=account[0], account_o=account[1])`

Comment: вывел {{ account_z }} и {{ account_o }} в шаблоне, но на странице пусто

Comment: @abby тогда уж сделайте не `cur.fetchall()`, а `cur.fetchone()`.